# Only using the 5V pin to power a display

Tags: gpio, hdmi, display

I have recently hooked up [an HDMI display](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N447AEY) to my Pi. I don't need the touch screen functionality, I just need it to receive power through the GPIO because the screen is detached.

[image: Detached Rpi display]

It works. I just connected the 5v pin and the ground pin to the appropriate sockets. But I am unsure if this is safe to do. Should I be using a resistor?

Comment: Your link is broken. Was this screen made to attach to the GPIO? If soyou should have no problem.

Comment: You are using the 5v pin for its intended use. It is connected to the power connector not the SOC gpio pins. I would be worried about plugging the wire to the wrong pin. Solder or wire wrap would seem safer, to me.

Comment: Inserting a resistor (WHY? What value?) will only create problems. See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any reason to use an in-line resistor.

If you are worried (which I wouldn't be) I would add an in-line fuse.

I'm not a electronics type though.